# Is there a way to see all the available context of React component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context, react-devtools

I'm working on a large React project, with tones of components and Providers that provide context (with `useContext`) to their children. I wish to see what the available contexts (from ancestors) for specific components are.

I tried to use the React DevTools Extension to find that but wihtout luck. It shows props, hooks, render tree, but not all the available contexts.